# SVN Auth not working

Tags: svn

I setup SVN with the 'password-db' enabled and I can still login without being auth:

```
#> cat authz
     [aliases]
     [groups]

#> cat passwd
     [users]
     somePrivateUser = SomeUserPass

#> cat svnserve.com
     [general]
     anon-access=none
     auth-access=write
     password-db=passwd
     realm=MyReals
```

**This works and checks out code:**

```
svn://somePrivateUser:SomeUserPass@server/mySvnPath/
```

**But so does this:**

```
svn://AnonFakeTest24323424@server/mySvnPath/
```

**And this:**

```
svn://server/mySvnPath/
```

**And this:**

```
svn://root@server/mySvnPath/
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong, I have restarted the server several times, everything checks out ok, but no mater what I can checkout the code without actually being auth'd by the server. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

In my authz conf I have defined access levels for the root path:

```
[/] 
* = 
somePrivateUser = rw
readOnlyUser = r
```

The * represents anonymous access.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, when I was testing the security I wasn't aware that TortoiseSVN caches the account, even if you try to use another account it still uses the first account that you add in. So, in effect, it is secure and it is that you can't change accounts once you have added one in TortoiseSVN.

@pikand - Thanks for responding so fast, I will look authz deeper for additional security.